# how to trigger the parentclass method from the child class?

Tags: actionscript, parent

I am new to AS 3.0.  Please clear my doubts. I am preparing the game, which will initially display login page. After username validation, it enters into the game.

I have 2 separate pages for login and a game. To load all these files, I have main file which loads the login page and game file. When the preloaded completes, the login page opens. Using application domain, I will access the login button.

When the login button is pressed, the user name and password entered will be sent to the server for validation. If authenticated, the user enters the game.

Now the problem is, I want to show game screen based on the username validation response. I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

super() from constructors

super.functionYouAreInheriting() from inherited methods

remember to pass the appropiate arguments as well

http://ntt.cc/2009/07/26/beginning-actionscript-3-super-this-setter-getter.html